# Verbose mode on spies in Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

When creating normal mocks you can make the mock verbose for easier debugging, e.g.:

```
 List mockWithLogger = mock(List.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
```

Example taken from [Mockito documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#verboseLogging()). How can I achieve similar result when using spies? I.e. I would like to write something like:

```
List spyWithLogger = spy(new MyList(), withSettings().verboseLogging());
```

but it doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: spy does not have a constructor like that..the way you are calling it

Comment: @Akshay, that is the point. If it had this constructor then I guess verbose logging would just work out of the box.

Comment: Follow this feature request: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1687

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the implementation of [spy](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/Mockito.java#L1978)  the following should work:

```
MyList myList = new MyList();
List spyWithLogger = mock(myList.getClass(), withSettings()
                                             .verboseLogging()
                                             .spiedInstance(myList)
                                             .defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS));
```